# How to scale SCNNodes to fit in a box?

Tags: swift, scenekit

I have multiple collada files with objects (humans) of various sizes, created from different 3D program sources.  I desire to scale the objects so they fit inside frame or box.  From my reading, I cant using the bounding box to scale the node, so what feature do you utilize to scale the nodes, relative to each other?

```
// humanNode = {...get node, which is some unknown size }

let (minBound, maxBound) = humanNode.boundingBox

let blockNode = SCNNode(geometry: SCNBox(width: 10, height: 10, length: 10, chamferRadius: 0))

// calculate scale factor so it fits inside of box without having known its size before hand.

s = { ...some method to calculate the scale to fit the humanNode into the box }

humanNode.scale = SCNVector3Make(s, s, s)
```

How get its size relative to the literal box I want to put it in and scale it?
Is it possible to draw the node off screen to measure its size?